# How can I apply a style to a parent element and inline child element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply to style both `<td>` element and a `<b>` element, with out having to duplicate any CSS. The `<b>` element is inside in my `<td>` element

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td id='special_instructions_cart' colspan='2'>
        <b id='special_instructions_cart'>Special Instructions</b> <!--Adds Extra Padding-->
        <br>Special Instructions goes here
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my CSS for the `<td>` element:

```
#special_instructions_cart {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

I tried doing this:

```
#special_instructions_cart, b {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

But it only applied extra padding to the words "Special Instructions".

Comment: a.) You cannot re-use id's in a single page. At best you'll get wonky results.

Comment: use different id like : "special_instruction_cart_1" and "special_instruction_cart_2"

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/X98nF/

Answer (score 3):

Your code needs a little bit of work. First of all, IDs (the `#` symbol indicates an ID) are meant to be used once and only once. If you need multiple elements to be grouped together with the same identifier, use the `class` feature, instead.

It's difficult for me to understand your question, but assuming I'm reading it correctly, you should start with the following code; I have simply switched your `ID` selector for a `Class` selector:

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class='special_instructions_cart' colspan='2'>
        <b class='special_instructions_cart'>Special Instructions</b> <!--Adds Extra Padding-->
    <br> Special Instructions goes here</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.special_instructions_cart {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Now, this code is a bit friendlier and more standards-compliant, but as you'll see if you apply it, the indention doesn't work for the second line. This is because the  cell is displayed as a special type: `table-cell`, and, in effect, displays `inline`, rather than block. So to really fix this, we will need to wrap the new line in a separate element, and then call it using CSS:

HTML:

```
 <tr>
    <td class='special_instructions_cart' colspan='2'>
        <b class='special_instructions_cart'>Special Instructions</b> <!--Adds Extra Padding-->
    <br> <span>Special Instructions goes here</span></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.special_instructions_cart, span {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

This second snippet should include the effect you're looking for. I've wrapped your second line in a `span` element and then added it to the CSS. The new CSS is applying the styles separately to both the element with class `.special_instructions_cart` and to the `span` element.

Finally, I would recommend that you consider whether you really want to use `<tr>` and `<td>` elements for this; tables are really meant for tabular data rather than page layout control.

Comment: TylerH. Thank you for your reply. I know that ID's are used for on element. I was just experimenting and forgot to change it. But its now using classes.

I don't think you got my questions. I want the "Special Instructions" to be bold. For some reason its not being bold, and I don't want the "Special Instructions" to be indented. For some reason its not bold and it gets indented. 

Also the reason why I am using tables for this is because I use it as an email to fax service and that service does not understand div's and floats correctly.

Comment: @user3790981 I see. Does this JSFiddle example have the requested effect?  http://jsfiddle.net/xzLgM/